# Geoserver source code: Understand what's happening when calling a WMS request

Tags: geoserver, eclipse

I try to get in touch with geoserver source code. I set it up in Eclipse like stated here (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/quickstart/index.html) and it's running.

Then I call a getCapabilities request with this URL: 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I try to understand now what's happening step by step in the code when calling this request. How would I do that?

I tried it with the eclipse debugger but it only shows what happens when calling the start.java class and not what actually happens on the running server.

The problem is that until now I only worked on code which I developed from scratch like in university lectures or some hobby stuff but never on a finished program source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in the Dispatcher, one in DefaultWebMapService, and go from there:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/ows/src/main/java/org/geoserver/ows/Dispatcher.java#L235

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/DefaultWebMapService.java#L286